# set Access database table field with form check box

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to set the value of a number field on a table using the value of a bound checkbox on a form. The value needs to be 40 if checked and 0 if unchecked. I'm new to this and have no idea where to start.

No, the checkbox was added to a form and is bound to a number field in the table. The data is imported from an antiquated system that uses codes that most users would not understand, so if it says 40 in the table I just want the form to show checked, all other values should show unchecked, and I want the user checking/unchecking the checkbox to update the table accordingly.

The checkbox is to indicate whether or not a customer has provided direct debit information. 40 would mean they have, anything other than 40 would mean they haven't.

Comment: Is this Check Box bound to a `Yes/No` field in the same table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way do this is using VBA in Access. The way you access VBA console in Access, is when in your form's design view, right-click the checkbox box control and choose "Build Event" from the menu. Make sure your control's Triple State is set to "Yes" in the property for the checkbox in the form's design view. Also, be certain that the checkbox's Control Source is pointed to the field in the table where you're putting the data.

Please note that prior to doing this, it is helpful to prefix your control's name... something like `chkDebitInfo`... "chk" stands for check box. You can change the name in the property sheet for the control, by clicking on the Other tab, and simply change the default name, which might say something like Check625. Also, you want to set the table field's data type to an "Integer" so it holds the value.

Once you're in the VBA console, after having chosen Build Event... you're presented with the control's sub procedure. I've done a sample for you:

```
Private Sub chkDebitInfo_Click()

If chkDebitInfo.Value = True Then
   chkDebitInfo.Value = 40         // Sets the checkbox to 40 if checked

ElseIf chkDebitInfo.Value = False Then
    chkDebitInfo.Value = 0        // Sets the checkbox to 0 if un-checked

End If

End Sub
```

I've commented the statements that set the checkbox values if checked or un-checked, so you don't have to add those. Just substitute the control name for your's, or use the default name if you haven't changed it, and you're good. Then when the check box is checked or not checked, you'll see the values populated in the database table.

Alternatively, you can set the checkbox to default value for when the form loads, but you haven't stated it, so I won't go into it. Hope this helps. Let me know if I need to expound further.

Comment: Thank you, this solution worked, however, it doesn't seem to update the table unless I click into one of the subforms of the form. I've tried putting it in the OnClick and OnMouseUp events of the checkbox as well as in the AfterUpdate event of the form without any success. Any idea of where it can be put to update automatically? Keep in mind, it will be the only control of the form that the users will be changing, so it will not be likely that they would be clicking on any other fields after checking/unchecking the box.

Comment: No, I don't know the design of how your actual form is. The solution I created for you should work to the end of updating the value in the database table. If the user clicks on the check, then according to the logic you've used or set up, the value will populate accordingly in the database table, where you have it going. Using Access 2013, it works just fine for me; don't know what version of Access your running. And without being able to see a working model of what you're doing, I can't put together the error you're getting. Also, you have no code stub for me to view, to see what you did.

Comment: Additionally, check the default value and make sure you assigned it a value in the code. Lastly, look at your Triple State, and toggle it to No/Yes, and see what that does for you. Again, much better to be able to see what's going on.

Comment: As this solution helped you, please check it, to conclude the question.