# Input mask in Access database

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a field with a customer ID that should be in the format of C0000000001, where it has a letter at the start and up to 10 numbers after the letter with leading zeros between the letter and the number. I want the users to be able to put in C1 and have the table save C0000000001 or C1234 and have the table save C0000001234.

I want the restriction to be on the hard data in the table. The table should contain the full customer ID but I only want the users to have to enter the C and the number of the customer when entering/searching for customers. I am using Access 2010.

I believe that the first character will always be a C, but either way, it would only be one alpha character if it wasn't.

I understand what you are saying, but the majority of the data (thousands of records) are going to be from another system that stores them that way. Doing it this way limits my margin of error. Otherwise, exports from the other system will need to be manually changed prior to being imported into the database and vice versa.

Searching would only be on existing records that will be saved in the C0000001234 format, but I would like user to be able to omit the leading zeros when entering the search criteria.

Comment: You need clarify the question. Where do you want to impose restrictions? On a form? In VBA? As a hard data restriction on a table?

Comment: This doesn't really sound like a job for an input mask.  Are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: Save yourself a LOT of trouble and don't do this. Use formatting to SHOW the data as C.....number but store it as an integer. I've used mixed keys like this before with Access and it leads to a large number of headaches.

Comment: Is the first letter always 'C'?

Comment: Seems to me you have two issues here: changing what is stored (*C1234* gets stored as *C0000001234*); and searching --- where you're probably not storing anything to the table before you search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be to use forms with associated queries using the FORMAT function.

You do need to clarify where you want this implemented, but I'm going to assume you have a table set up and that you would like to be able to enter/search data from a form.

I'll create one form for input `frmAdd`. For the input form, I created a query that would run when a button on the form was pressed. Add two text boxes `newID` and `newOther` to the forms which are unbounded but which the user can use to enter data. The query will then pull that data and append it to your table in an altered format. Here's the SQL for that query:

```
INSERT INTO Customers ( [Customer ID], [Other Field] )
SELECT Left([Forms]![frmAdd]![newID].[value],1) 
& Format(Right([Forms]![frmAdd]![newID].[value],Len([Forms]![frmAdd]![newID].[value])-1),"0000000000") 
AS Expr1, Forms![frmAdd]!newOther AS Expr2
FROM Customers;
```

I'm not sure exactly what search functionality you're looking for, but this query would pull up the record data matching that of a `frmSearch` with a textbox `search` which would have the format C### or whatever entered in:

```
SELECT Left([Customers].[Customer ID],1) & Replace(LTrim(Replace(Right([Customers].[Customer ID],9),'0',' ')),' ','0') 
AS Expr1, Customers.[Other Field]
FROM Customers
WHERE (((Customers.[Customer ID])=Left([Forms]![frmSearch]![search].[value],1) 
& Format(Right([Forms]![frmSearch]![search].[value],Len([Forms]![frmSearch]![search].[value])-1),"0000000000")));
```

Applying the input mask is just a way to *ensure* that your data is correct. If you feel the need to use one, go to the table in Design View and click on the Data Type box for the customer ID field. Find Input Mask under Field Properties -> General and click it. Then hit go to the toolbar -> Design tab -> Builder. This will walk you through it.

Answer (score 1):

This question, combined with your previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28116008/2144390), suggest to me that you are trying very hard to have the data structure in your Access database *exactly match* the legacy system from which you receive bulk updates. That may not be necessary, or even desirable.

For example, instead of maintaining the CustomerId as `Text(11)` (as in the old system) you could store it in your Access database as

- CustomerIdPrefix: `Text(1)`, and
- CustomerIdNumber: `Long Integer` or perhaps `Decimal` if the numeric part really can exceed 2,147,483,647

Your Customers table in Access could also include a calculated field named CustomerId as

```
[CustomerIdPrefix] & Right("0000000000" & [CustomerIdNumber], 10)
```

to give you a single 'C0000012345' value for display purposes.

For searching, your form could have a Text Box for the Prefix (default value: 'C') and another text box for the numeric part. The search could then use a condition like

```
[CustomerIdPrefix] = txtPrefix.Value AND [CustomerIdNumber] = txtNumber.Value
```

or, if the user wanted to create a Filter on the Form (or Datasheet View) it would probably be sufficient to just filter on the number part.

If you ever needed to feed information back to the legacy system you could just export a query that includes the [CustomerId] calculated field (and omits [CustomerIdPrefix] and [CustomerIdNumber]) and you'd be fine.

Comment: Can I ask why it wouldn't be desirable to keep the data in the same format that it will be used? Is it just because of the complexity of keeping it that way, or is there another issue?

Comment: The data will be "used" in two different ways: once imported into Access it will be "used" (to some extent) in Access, and if updated information gets fed back to the legacy application it will get "used" there, too. A few simple transformations you can apply on import, with corresponding inverse transformations on export, can free you from the complications and restrictions imposed by the design of the legacy application. You get a better Access application, and you lose nothing in the process.

Answer (score -1):

Input mask is not the answer for this. Input mask forces the user to input the data in a certain manner. What you need is some VBA code to run in the AfterUpdate event on a form. There's no way within the table to force the data into this pattern allowing the input method that you've requested.

There may be a more efficient way to do this, but this does the job.

http://pineboxsolutions.com/access/customeriddemo.accdb

Comment: *The requested URL /access/customeriddemo.accdb was not found on this server.*

Comment: re: *"There's no way within the table to force the data into this pattern"* - Actually, in Access 2010 it can be done with a Before Change [data macro](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/create-a-data-macro-HA010378170.aspx), but that might not be the best approach as I explain my my answer to this question.

Comment: While I'll concede that a data macro might work, and I agree that your method is a likely better approach, that's not really what the OP asked for. The user wants to be able to type in "C1" or "C1234" or something else in that pattern and have it conform to the format listed. In some ways neither was my answer, so I guess that ultimately what the user wants to do isn't really something Access is accommodating at.